# How to check Sybase IQ connection status in shell script

Tags: sql, database, shell, sybase, sap-iq

I'm using dbisql to connect to Sybase IQ database.
script is this below:

```
RESULT=$(dbisql -c "uid=dba;pwd=aaaaaa;eng=${ENGINE_NAME}" -onerror continue -nogui read ./dbScript/load_A_L_ART_PORT_D.sql [$FILE_NAME])
  echo $RESULT |grep -q "SQLCODE"
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
    write_log "[File]: ${FILE_NAME} import failed ..." ${LOG_NAME};
    write_log "ERROR Message: ${RESULT}" ${LOG_NAME};
  else
    mv $FILE_NAME ${FILE_NAME}_imported
    mv ${FILE_NAME}_imported $IMPORTED_DIR
    write_log "[File]: ${FILE_NAME} import succeed ..." ${LOG_NAME};
    write_log "Import Message: ${RESULT}" ${LOG_NAME};
  fi
```

while database is running, everything works fine. but when database is shutdown.
Error occurs:

```
[2] Please input database engine name[eng].(eg:iqcoor_zdc)
    INPUT: 
iqcoor_zdc
[1/50]Importing A_L_ART_PORT_H ...
**Could not connect to the database.
Database server not found
SQLCODE=-100, ODBC 3 State="08001"**
```

how to check if the database is running before execute the sql scripts?
or other connection problems.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test whether the IQ server is running by using the 'dbping' utility.